# IntelliJ IDEA: How do I verify and/or change my BitBucket git credentials?

Tags: intellij-idea, bitbucket

As per [this blog post](https://bitbucket.org/blog/deprecating-atlassian-account-password-for-bitbucket-api-and-git-activity), BitBucket is disabling account password usage for HTTPS access in March.

I've created one of these "app password" credentials - but how do I make IDEA to start using it?

I'm pretty sure I originally set my IDEA up to access via HTTPS and just put my BitBucket account username/password when prompted.

In my IDEA Git settings, `Use credential helper` is not enabled (so Windows credential manager is not relevant, pretty sure IDEA is saving into its Keepass file in the settings directory).

In other scenarios with changed account details, I've generally just tried to access the repo, waited for IDEA to fail and prompt for details, then entered the new credentials.

How do I tell IDEA to use the new password, given that the old password still works?

Things I don't want to do:

- I don't want to reset all my credentials, just this one BitBucket password.
- I don't want to change over to using the Windows credential manager.
- I don't want to change over to SSH.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case someone still needs this info, here's how I did it. I'm not an expert - far from it, but I got it working...

### How to check credentials in IntelliJ

1. Menu Git > Manage Remotes...
   [Git_ManageRemotes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRzQa.png)
2. Check remote URL in "Define Remote" screen and press OK.
   When you press OK it will re-authenticate, in my case this gave me a window where I had to enter my app password.
   If you don't get the credential popup (that means your current credentials are still valid), maybe remove your current remote URL and re-add it, to force a username/password popup.
   [Git_Remotes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vyO7.png)

### How to configure your App Password in BitBucket

1. Follow the instructions on the blog post you linked (copied below for archiving)

> To create an app password:
>
> - From your profile and settings avatar, select Personal settings.
> - Select App passwords under Access management.
> - Select Create app password.
> - Give the app password a name related to the application that will use the password.
> - Select the specific access and permissions you want to assign to this application password.
> - Copy the generated password and either record or paste it into the application you want to give access. The password is only displayed this one time.

2. Which permissions does your App Password need?
   In my case, all I needed was pull/push of the code, so the below permissions were enough (Pull Requests-write, the rest is automatically enabled)
   [AppPassword_Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKSvM.png)

Comment: The second step for "How to check credentials in IntelliJ" is a great way to update credentials in keychain/keepass. Your guide is really accurate

Comment: Didn't work.  Pressing Ok or touching the field gives a spinner (meaning might be checking the remote, dunno), but doesn't prompt for a new password or anything.

Comment: Note: if you try to remove/add a replacement "origin" remote, IDEA/Git will lose info about about locally tracked branches and pull etc. will stop working.  Before you can fix, you must do a "fetch" and then you can follow the fix dialog to select your original branch as tracked.

Answer (score 1):

Also remember that the App Passwords only work with with your Bitbucket Username and NOT with your email address.

So if you are trying to move from the old style of authentication, to the App Passwords, you also need to update your username if the user name is set to your email address

Comment: saved my life, 10x

Answer (score 0):

I followed these step in Webstorm:

Git > Manage Remotes > select repo > OK -> webstorm asked me to re-authenticate and I specified the app password generated from Bitbucket.
But terminal still showing this message:

> remote: Yo are using an account password for Git over HTTPS.
> Beginning March 1, 2022, users are required to use app passwords
> for Git over HTTPS. To avoid any disruptions, change
> the password used in your Git client to an app password.
> Note, these credentials may have been automatically stored in
> your Git client and/or a credential manager such as Git
> Credential Manager (GCM).

If I retry this procedure, webstorm doesn't show anymore the credential popup.
I also tried "invalidate cache and restart" in webstorm, but nothing changes.

There's something else to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I solved this problem.. I modified my Bitbucket credential in Windows Credential Management. I've updated password field with the "app password" generated from Bitbucket and the message in terminal isn't no longer shown. I hope I found the correct solution..!!